# Syntastic Error with Fortran Module

Tags: vim, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, syntastic

I use both intel and gnu fortran compilers. Syntastic gives the following errors when I compile my module, with these settings:

1. *syntastic_fortran_compiler* set to **'ifort'** & using `ifort -c my_mod.f90`, then it displays an error on the `USE my_mod` line.
2. *syntastic_fortran_compiler* set to **'gfortran'** & using `gfortran -c my_mod.f90`, then it displays an error on the `CALL subroutine` line.

To change the value of *syntastic_fortran_compiler*, I edit the file: syntastic-checkers.txt by accessing it through `:help syntastic-checkers-fortran` in vim.

There is no problem with the code running though; everything is fine. The module does what it is supposed to. I like the **loc_list** when it displays errors, but it is irritating when it comes up with a non-removable, non-error. For now, I have set `let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 0`.

This is produced on a machine with **gcc version 4.8.4**. An interesting thing is that when I do this on a machine with gcc version 5.*, the gfortran error disappears. Also, I use **ifort version 16.0.3** .

**EDIT1**: I see the errors when I open the main program file with vim after I compile as above.

**EDIT2**: As [lcd047](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658042/lcd047) mentions in the comments, I am supposed to add `let g:syntastic_fortran_compiler ="ifort"` to my .vimrc. Doing so resolves error(1), and now both cases produce error(2).

**EDIT3**:

The funniest thing happened. After I performed EDIT2, I indented the code inside the SUBROUTINE contained in my MODULE, because the cursor kept jumping one indent every time I pressed enter, and it was getting irritating (up until now all code in the module was without indentation).

Then, when I opened my main file this time, *syntastic* actually tells me what is wrong as an error message (till now it only said error). Message: *The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.* It underlined all the REALs amongst the args (I have REAL and INTEGER args).

So then I open my_mod.f90 to check; everything seems okay. And this time when I open main.f90, there isn't an error anymore. What I wrote above is all I did. I have no idea how the error disappeared.

**EDIT4**: The above effect is reproducible. When `g:syntastic_fortran_compiler = "ifort"`, if I compile once with gfortran, and open the file, *syntastic* says that it does not recognize the module. That is okay. Now, if I compile again with ifort, *syntastic* gives that error message of differing types again. Closing and opening the file again removes the error.

Comment: Syntastic doesn't know, nor cares, about the contents of your files.  What it does is run external checkers, then shows you the results in a window.  If you don't like the results you get then you need to change the way checkers are run, and / or filter results.  To __see__ how syntastic runs the checkers enable debugging and read the logs (`:h syntastic-debug`).  To __change__ how syntastic runs the checkers set the various checker options (`:h syntastic-fortran-gfortran`).  To filter results set `syntastic_fortran_gfortran_quiet_messages` (`:h syntastic-filtering-errors`).

Comment: @lcd047 So are you saying that I should forget the fact that a syntax checker is telling me that there is something wrong and just suppress the message instead of looking for the root of the issue?

Comment: No, I'm saying you should run the checks with the same options as the builds.  Then you'd get the same results.

Comment: _To change the value of `syntastic_fortran_compiler`, I edit the file: syntastic-checkers.txt_ - That's a help file, editing it has exactly zero effect on syntastic's working.  You're supposed to set the variable `g:syntastic_fortran_compiler` in your vimrc, not in the help file.

Comment: Oh! Shoot... Thanks! I added `let g:syntastic_fortran_compiler ="ifort"`. Okay, now both cases show an error on the `CALL subroutine` line.

Comment: @lcd047 Look at EDITs 3 and 4. The issue is basically resolved. Could you put your 3rd comment as an answer so I can accept? Or is this too trivial an issue? It was quite stupid of me to not have realised that that was a help file. But thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not very good to have edit1...edit99. A question should be for the future visitors in the form of a clear formulation of a problem for which there is an answer below. Notice the link **edited + date"** just below the question. Enyone can click there to see the history. No need to Have your **Edit42** with changes what to you wrote above it. Just  rewrite your question when editing.